# put menus, defined in packages, as submenu into own menu-bar menu

Tags: menu-bar, menus

**Introduction:** The menu-bar is a nice institution of emacs to remember a command and its shortcut. Using then `easy-menu-define` for defining own menus is pretty awesome with regard to this purpose. So it is possible to cluster certain commands or stuff them into submenus.

```
(easy-menu-define my-menu global-map
    "My Menu docstring"
    '("My-Menu-Title"
      [ "foo item" foo-item-callback ]
      ("foo submenu"
       [ "foo submenu item" foo-sub-item-callback ]))
```

Also some packages (for example: `Hide/Show` from `hideshow.el`) use `easy-menu-define` to define own top-level menus. They define it like this:

```
(easy-menu-define hs-minor-mode-menu hs-minor-mode-map
  "Menu used when hideshow minor mode is active."
  '("Hide/Show"
     ...)
```

**Question:** I'm sure it somehow possible to stuff this, in package `Hide/Show`, defined menu `hs-minor-mode-menu` as a **submenu** into my own defined menu `my-menu`.
How could I achieve this?

*Note:* I do not want to have the `hs-minor-mode-menu` as popup menu. This could be easily achieved by calling `hs-minor-mode-menu` as menu item callback. I'd like a real submenu.

*Edit:* [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26638015/elisp-easy-menu-positioning/43618554#43618554) is working to relocate my own defined menus, but not for the Hide/Show menu. Also this answer does not help to remove the `hs-minor-mode-menu` from global menubar.